# Compare Database and Insert into existing database if new record added

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `dbo.so , dbo.restageso`

i want to compare this two tables, and if there is different data, new data will insert into `dbo.so` while repeated data will drop. Please assist.

Comment: dbo and MySQL? Somewhat unusual combo...

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of replication/synchronization?

Comment: Yes, synchronization. Actually i am quite new to SQL.

Comment: yes, i am using MS SQL Server

Comment: Have you try by yourself to get information about update and union ?

Comment: I have try the except function, and i manage to find out the different, but now i need update the different data into the dbo.so database

Comment: Update or insert?

Comment: compare, find difference / new record, insert into database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.so
(col1, col2, ... coln)
SELECT col1,col2,..coln FROM
(
SELECT col1,col2,..coln FROM dbo.restageso 
EXCEPT
SELECT col1,col2,..coln FROM dbo.so 
) A
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: INSERT INTO dbo.so
(SO, Description, ... Amount)
SELECT * FROM

(
SELECT SO,Description,..Amount FROM dbo.restageso 
EXCEPT
SELECT SO,Description,..Amount FROM dbo.so 
)A

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "..Amount" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "..Amount" could not be bound.

Comment: refer Stackoverflow questions for the above error. You can easily correct it. It may be due to some typo

Comment: Hi is working now.
Is there any statement to bulk insert txt file with tab deliminated.

Comment: @Prabu are you using c# or any other languages along with sql-server? If yes you can open the text file and insert into database using the features in the proramming language

Comment: It is better to ask it as separate question. Feel free to upvote and mark the above answer as correct if it solved your problem.